# How much energy would it require to send something in deep space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work

Since if i throw something up ,it's gonna come down ; but if i throw it enough fast it's not going to come back since the $g$ gets smaller with distance, So it'll go and slow down ....

If i send it with any less energy ,it'll come back ,;
Assuming there is nothing in the way or other gravitational fields

Btw is that energy equal to The pe of the object relative to the earth's center ;Not just 9.8 *d but the integral

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity You need about speed of about 11.2 km/s,  The energy depends on the mass of the object

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133494/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring, not just related but likely a duplicate

Comment: What you are looking for is Escape velocity. Escape velocity from Earth is about 11.2 km/s. Also what do you mean by "Deep Space"? Does it mean interstellar Space? In that case we would require a bit of math to figure it out